# developing windows phone 8 app with javascript using visual studio 2013 ultimate update 2

Tags: javascript, html, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I want to develop windows phone 8 app with java-script using visual studio ultimate 2013 update 2 but i couldn't find there option for windows phone 8, there is only option for 8.1, please help me understand how to built app for windows phone 8 app with java-script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Phone 8.0 **does not** support JavaScript projects.  But you still can use a WebBrowser component to load in your html and javascript as mentioned [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/thunbrynt/archive/2014/04/14/windows-phone-8-1-for-developers-for-the-html-javascript-developer.aspx).

Windows Phone 8.1 does support JavaScript projects.